# Are the properties in Power Shell FTP module(WebAdministration) Case-Sensitive?

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool, web-administration

PowerShell is case insensitive language and so are the modules like `WebAdministration` expected to be.

**This doesn't work:**

```
PS IIS:\AppPools> Set-ItemProperty .\DefaultAppPool -Name Enable32BitAppOnWin64 -Value $true
```

**Whereas this works:**

```
PS IIS:\AppPools> Set-ItemProperty .\DefaultAppPool -Name enable32BitAppOnWin64 -Value $true
```

Difference is only in capital and small letter 'e' in property name. 
Moreover, the first command doesn't even throw any error.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/15077202-make-propeties-name-case-insensitive-for-creating

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bug since the behaviour differs for different Windows versions (e. g. for Windows 10, the first letter must be lowercase whereas for Windows 7 not).

There is also a [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36506010/1163423).

Comment: yeah, seems like a bug. First i doesn't do what its expected to and second it doesn't give out any errors.